# Unable to replace string inside a String in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to replace a few sub strings inside a string. But my code doesn't seem to work.

```
val listOfMaleWords = listOf(" him", " he", " his")
val listOfFemaleWords = listOf(" her", " she", " her")

fun modifyIdeaForGender(rawIdea : String, desiredGender : String): String {
    var theRawIdea = rawIdea
    if (desiredGender == "FEMALE") {
        println("desired gender is FEMALE")
        listOfMaleWords.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
            theRawIdea.replace(element, listOfFemaleWords[index])
        }
    } else {
        println("desired gender is MALE")
        listOfFemaleWords.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
            theRawIdea.replace(element, listOfMaleWords[index])
        }
    }
    return theRawIdea
}

fun main() {
    var sampleString : String = "Tell him, he is special"
    println(modifyIdeaForGender(sampleString, "FEMALE"))
}
```

Expected Output :

```
"Tell her, she is special"
```

Current Output :

```
"Tell him, he is special" // no change
```

Whats wrong with my code? The current output doesn't replace the string characters at all.

Comment: Strings are immutable. i.e. `theRawIdea.replace` returns a new string.

Comment: `replace` does not modify the string you call it on but returns a new modified string. But you are never using that result, so it's lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` returns a new `String` that you are discarding immediately. It *does not* mutate `theRawIdea` itself, so you should assign it back to `theRawIdea` yourself. For example:

```
theRawIdea = theRawIdea.replace(element, listOfFemaleWords[index])
```

Though this would modify `theRawIdea` as you desire, it wouldn't replace the pronouns correctly. Once it replaces the "him"s with "her"s, it would try to replace the "he"s with "she"s. But note that "he" a substring of "her"! So this would produce:

```
Tell sher, she is special
```

This could be fixed by reordering the lists, putting the "he"-"she" pair first, or by using regex, adding `\b` word boundary anchors around the words:

```
// note that you should not have spaces before the words if you decide to use \b
val listOfMaleWords = listOf("him", "he", "his")
val listOfFemaleWords = listOf("her", "she", "her")

...

theRawIdea = theRawIdea.replace("\\b$element\\b".toRegex(), listOfFemaleWords[index])
```

Note that this doesn't account for capitalisation or the fact that changing from female gender pronouns to male ones is inherently broken. Your current code would change all `her` to `him`. It would require some more complicated natural language processing to accurately do this task in general.

Taking all that into account, I've rewritten your code with [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html):

```
fun modifyMaleIdeaToFemaleGender(rawIdea : String): String {
    var theRawIdea = rawIdea
    // if you really want to do the broken female to male case, then this would be
    // listOfFemaleWords zip listOfMaleWords
    // and the loop below can stay the same
    val zipped = listOfMaleWords zip listOfFemaleWords
    zipped.forEach { (target, replacement) -> 
        theRawIdea = theRawIdea.replace("\\b$target\\b".toRegex(), replacement) 
    }
    return theRawIdea
}
```

You can also use [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) to avoid reassigning `theRawIdea`:

```
fun modifyIdeaToFemaleGender(rawIdea : String): String {
    val zipped = listOfMaleWords zip listOfFemaleWords
    return zipped.fold(rawIdea) { acc, (target, replacement) ->
        acc.replace("\\b$target\\b".toRegex(), replacement)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code assumes that the `replace()` method performs an in-place mutation of the string. However, the string with the replaced values are returned by the `replace()`. So you need to change your code to contain something like:

```
theRawIdea = theRawIdea.replace(element, listOfFemaleWords[index])
```

To do this, you will have to use a conventional loop instead of `listOfMaleWords.forEachIndexed` style looping.

Comment: Why switch to a conventional loop? Why doesn't `forEachIndexed` work?